# Create a Mat from a PvBuffer in C# using eBUS SDK and EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv, opencv3.0, gige-sdk

I'm using EmguCV 3.4.1 and the eBUS SDK. I have video coming in over GigE and I would like to convert the PvBuffer to a MAT so I can use OpenCV to create a display a histogram.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and narrow the question down to what exactly seems to be the problem. So far your "question" doesn't have a question mark in it and *looks* like you're waiting for someone to just write code for you for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed a similar style to how you create a Mat in C++. Unfortunately this solution requires marking the project as unsafe.

```
    unsafe private Mat convertPvBufferToMat(PvBuffer aBuffer)
    {
        PvImage lImage = aBuffer.Image;
        lImage.Alloc(lImage.Width, lImage.Height, PvPixelType.Mono16);
        int[] sizes = new int[2] { (int)lImage.Height, (int)lImage.Width };
        Mat aMat = new Mat(sizes, DepthType.Cv16U, (IntPtr)lImage.DataPointer);

        return aMat;
    }
```

I'm taking images from an infared camera outputing 16 bit grayscale images.